# Вызвать у реализации Button метод onClick суперкласса

Tags: android

Всем привет. По заголовку не очень понятно, что требуется, поэтому объясняю: 
Есть класс ButtonBack, наследованный от Button. В нем реализован интерфейс OnClickListener.

В классе активности я объявляю ButtonBack:

```
ButtonBack mButton = (ButtonBack)findViewById....;
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
   @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // тут нужно вызвать метод onClick из класса ButtonBack
            mButton.setBackground(....);
        }
    });
```

Как мне вызвать onClick из ButtonBack?

Comment: вы точно хотите вызвать onClick из ButtonBack или все таки из родительского класса Button ? Просто ваш коментарии и так внутри метода onClick от экземпляра класса ButtonBack

Comment: @alexoander ButtonBack наследован от Button. В ButtonBack реализован onClickListener. В активности у кнопки mButton я хочу вызвать onClick, который реализован в ButtonBack

Comment: Хм, все оказалось гораздо проще. Смысла реализовывать onClick в ButtonBack не было. Сделал просто метод и вызвал его в активности, где мне надо.

Comment: Ну раз ты нашел ответ сам - оформи его как ответ. И если с кодом то было бы отлично

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, все очень просто. Нужно было создать метод в классе ButtonBack и вызвать его в классе активности. Т.е:

```
public class ButtonBack extends Button {

    public ButtonBack(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ButtonBack(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public void changeBackground() {
        this.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yellow_oval_button));
    }
}
```

И в активности вызвать его:

```
    mButtonBack = (ButtonBack)findViewById(R.id.image_game_button_back);
    mButtonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mButtonBack.changeBackground();
            ImageGameActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
```